# Slow program- Mathematica shuts down

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, dynamic, polynomials

I've been trying to draw dynamic pictures of level sets of certain polynomials. The code right now looks like that :

```
 n = 2;
 dp[w_, z__] := ((-1)^(n))*
 Product[w - Complex @@ zz, {zz, {z}}]/
 Product[Complex @@ zz, {zz, {z}}]
 dp[w, Sequence @@ z] (* not really needed here*)
 Integrate[dp[w, Sequence @@ z], w] (*not really needed either*)


 DynamicModule[{z = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {n, 2}]},
 Dynamic[
 Show[ContourPlot[
 With[{w = x + I*y}, 
  Abs[Integrate[dp[Q, Sequence @@ z], Q] /. Q -> w] - Abs[w]] == 
  0, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True],
  Graphics[
  Evaluate@
   Table[With[{i = i}, Locator[Dynamic[z[[i]]]]], {i, n}]]]]]
```

What this does is it builds a polynomial $dp(w)$ having n roots (think of this as the derivative of some polynomial $p(w)$) and it retrieves the anti-derivative that corresponds to const=0, $p(w)$, by integrating. Then I want to draw dynamic pictures of the level curves $|p(w)|=|w|$ that I can change by moving the roots of $p'(w)$ (`dp[w]` in the code ) around. It seems to work for n<=3 but it's very slow and for n>3 the program shuts down. Is there anyway to prevent this/make the program faster? I would like to be able to work with at least n=6. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Integration is costly, so it's not a great thing to dump into a dynamic construct.

Comment: However, your code (with the exception of all locators moving in sync on M version 8) runs fine at `n=6` on my machine. Not particularly smooth, but 10 fps or so.

Comment: Do you think it might be a lot faster if I replace the integral by a finite Riemann sum ( possibly with lots of terms) ? Also, do you know if there's a way to interactively input the roots, say by clicking on the plane ? If so, I might be able to avoid the dynamic construct.

Comment: It's certainly possible to input the roots like that, though I can't off the top of my head say exactly how, I'd need to browse the documentation for a bit first. The best solution by far would be to find an analytical expression for the integral. I'm not sure, how you intend to get a Riemann sum for an indefinite integral here. Does the code run much slower on your machine, than on mine?

Comment: I see. I will look it up. Yes, it is significantly slower. It can barely handle n=3 and sometimes it even shuts down when I move the roots near some "bad" points. No question for n=4; it shuts down with no output at all.

Comment: I suggest coding the analytical expression for the antiderivative. It is quite trivial. Compare the output of `Expand[Product[Q-q[i],{i,n}]]` with the output of `Subsets[Range[n],n]`. That should give a good clue how to programatically write down an analytical expression.

Comment: I now also see the problem. I have indeed noticed that dynamic constructs run much slower in M v.10, as compared to M v.8. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I have tuned your code a bit and it now works reasonably on v.10. 7 locators are ok, 10 gets terrible, but nothing crashes.

This is the integral of your function. You can compare it to `Integrate[dp[w, z], w]`:

```
p[w_, n_Integer, z__] := 
 Sum[Total@(((-1)^n w^(n - i + 1))/(n - i + 1)
       Times @@@ Subsets[-(Complex @@@ {z}), {i}]), {i, 0, n}]/
  Times[Sequence @@ (Complex @@@ {z})]
```

I have made it a function of `n` too, to localize the variables as much as possible.

```
DynamicModule[{z, n = 10}, z = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {n, 2}]; 
 Dynamic[Show[
   ContourPlot[
    With[{w = x + I*y}, Abs[p[w, n, Sequence @@ z]] - Abs[w]] == 
     0, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True],
    Graphics[
    Evaluate@
     Table[With[{i = i}, Locator[Dynamic[z[[i]]]]], {i, n}]]]]]
```

As you can see, `n` is now assigned a value within the module. Try starting small and working up. `n=6` should not be a problem.

Comment: `Evaluate[With[{w = x + I*y}, Abs[p[w, n, Sequence @@ z]] - Abs[w]] == 0]` will speed things up, so that `n >= 10` is good. (+1)